# Не работает плагин gulp-rigger, почему?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Установил этот плагин, пытаюсь импортировать файл, в `index.html` ввожу `//= footer.html` , но у меня не получается.

Браузер выводит это просто как строку.

Весь проект [можно скачать здесь](https://github.com/dimangry/gulpProject1).

Мой **gulpfile.js**:

```
var gulp         = require('gulp'),
    sass         = require('gulp-sass'),
    rigger       = require('gulp-rigger'),
    browserSync  = require('browser-sync'),
    del          = require('del');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src('app/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function(){
    browserSync({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'app'
        },
        notify: false
    })
});

gulp.task('html', function(){
    gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe(rigger())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});


gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return del.sync('dist'); 
});

gulp.task('watch', ['browser-sync', 'sass'], function(){
    gulp.watch('app/sass/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('app/*.html', browserSync.reload);
    gulp.watch('app/js/**/*.js', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean', 'sass'],  function(){
        var buildCss = gulp.src('app/css/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));

        var buildFonts = gulp.src('app/fonts/**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/fonts'))

        var buildJs = gulp.src('app/js/**/*') 
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))

        var buildHtml = gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
})
```

Файл **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "project1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.5",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-rigger": "^0.5.8",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Когда в консоли вводим команду `gulp html` , начала появляться **ошибка**:

> dimon@dimon-Lenovo-B560:~/Рабочий стол/project1$ gulp html
>       [22:45:03] Using gulpfile ~/Рабочий стол/project1/gulpfile.js
>       [22:45:03] Starting 'html'...
>       [22:45:03] Finished 'html' after 16 ms
>       buffer.js:274
>         throw new TypeError(kFromErrorMsg);
>         ^
>
> ```
> TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.
>     at fromObject (buffer.js:274:9)
>     at Function.Buffer.from (buffer.js:106:10)
>     at new Buffer (buffer.js:85:17)
>     at /home/dimon/Рабочий стол/project1/node_modules/gulp-rigger/index.js:20:29
>     at Rigger.<anonymous> (/home/dimon/Рабочий стол/project1/node_modules/rigger/index.js:719:9)
>     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>     at Rigger.emit (events.js:188:7)
>     at /home/dimon/Рабочий стол/project1/node_modules/rigger/index.js:252:16
>     at /home/dimon/Рабочий стол/project1/node_modules/rigger/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:232:13
>     at /home/dimon/Рабочий стол/project1/node_modules/rigger/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:113:21
> dimon@dimon-Lenovo-B560:~/Рабочий стол/project1$
> ```

Структура проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

3 ситуации при которых получается такая ошибка:

- Расширение файла отличается от того, в который вы подключаете файл
- В конце пути присутствуют пустые символы (я очень долго ломал голову когда искал:) )
- Неправильный путь

Answer (score -1):

В путях к файлу не должно быть кириллицы:

`at /home/dimon/Рабочий стол/project1/node_modules/rigger/index.js:252:16`