# TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object

Tags: javascript, gulp, npm

```
buffer.js:183
throw new TypeError(kFromErrorMsg);
^

TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.
at Function.Buffer.from (buffer.js:183:11)
at new Buffer (buffer.js:158:17)
at C:\Users\Владислав\Desktop\StartHtml-master\startHtml\node_modules\gulp-rigger\index.js:20:29
at Rigger.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Владислав\Desktop\StartHtml-master\startHtml\node_modules\rigger\index.js:719:9)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Rigger.emit (events.js:211:7)
at C:\Users\Владислав\Desktop\StartHtml-master\startHtml\node_modules\rigger\index.js:252:16
at C:\Users\Владислав\Desktop\StartHtml-master\startHtml\node_modules\rigger\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:232:13
at C:\Users\Владислав\Desktop\StartHtml-master\startHtml\node_modules\rigger\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:113:21
at C:\Users\Владислав\Desktop\StartHtml-master\startHtml\node_modules\rigger\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:24:16
```

Не могу понять в чем проблема пытаюсь запустить сборку gulp и выдает эту ошибку.
Вот ссылка на сборку https://github.com/vladseverin/StartHtml/tree/master/startHtml

Comment: Что у вас такое `kFromErrorMsg`? Какого он типа?

Comment: [TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.](https://github.com/kuzyk/gulp-rigger/issues/15) - в комментариях _You dont have navigation.html in partials directory, add it and check_

Comment: Возможно дубликат: [Не работает плагин gulp-rigger, почему?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/606400/186999)